# Using variable in property settings for postgreSql in bicep template throws error

Tags: postgresql, azure, if-statement, conditional-statements, azure-bicep

I'm trying to deploy a postgreSql server and database using a bicep template. Depending on the environment parameter there should be different settings.
It functions well for the SKU if I write

```
  sku : (environment == 'production') ? {
    name: ...
  } : {
    name: ...
  }
```

The same logic doesn't work for the properties (just an excerpt)

```
properties: (environment == 'production') ? {
    storageProfile: {
      geoRedundantBackup: 'Enabled'
    }
  } : {
    storageProfile: {
      geoRedundantBackup: 'Disabled'
    }
  }
```

The deployment fails. In the Azure portal I get an error with Status 'Method not allowed'
and details

```
    "error": {
        "code": "FeatureSwitchNotEnabled",
        "message": "Requested feature is not enabled"
    }
```

Any idea why that is happening? Is it not possible to switch the properties? The error message itself doesn't give precise information.

I tried to move the condition on different levels, e.g. directly to the geoRedundantBackup setting or to storage profile. I am getting the same error every time.
I tried to use a variable instead of a conditional, which didn't help.

Comment: Can you refer this github issue regarding the same error -https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/8534

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I now found out that my issue has nothing to do with the conditionals I am setting up, but some other server settings. I'll try the suggestions from the github issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to set property according to the environment, As a workaround you can directly use this code:-

```json
backup: {
      backupRetentionDays: 7
      geoRedundantBackup: environment == 'production' ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled'
    }
```

I have referred the code from this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/single-server/quickstart-create-postgresql-server-database-using-bicep?tabs=CLI) to deploy Azure PostgreSQL with above settings:-

**main.bicep:-**

> ```json
>  @description('Server Name for Azure Database for PostgreSQL')
>
> param  serverName  string
>
> @description('Database administrator login name')
>
> @minLength(1)
>
> param  administratorLogin  string
>
>   
>
> @description('Database administrator password')
>
> @minLength(8)
>
> @secure()
>
> param  administratorLoginPassword  string
>
>   
>
> param  environment  string = 'production'
>
>   
>
> @description('Azure Database for PostgreSQL compute capacity in vCores
> (2,4,8,16,32)')
>
> param  skuCapacity  int = 2
>
>   
>
> @description('Azure Database for PostgreSQL sku name ')
>
> param  skuName  string = 'GP_Gen5_2'
>
>   
>
> @description('Azure Database for PostgreSQL Sku Size ')
>
> param  skuSizeMB  int = 51200
>
>   
>
> @description('Azure Database for PostgreSQL pricing tier')
>
> @allowed([
>
> 'Basic'
>
> 'GeneralPurpose'
>
> 'MemoryOptimized'
>
> ])
>
> param  skuTier  string = 'GeneralPurpose'
>
>   
>
> @description('Azure Database for PostgreSQL sku family')
>
> param  skuFamily  string = 'Gen5'
>
>   
>
> @description('PostgreSQL version')
>
> @allowed([
>
> '9.5'
>
> '9.6'
>
> '10'
>
> '10.0'
>
> '10.2'
>
> '11'
>
> ])
>
> param  postgresqlVersion  string = '11'
>
>   
>
> @description('Location for all resources.')
>
> param  location  string = resourceGroup().location
>
>   
>
> @description('PostgreSQL Server backup retention days')
>
> param  backupRetentionDays  int = 7
>
>   
>
> // @description('Geo-Redundant Backup setting')
>
> // param geoRedundantBackup string = 'Disabled'
>
>   
>
> @description('Virtual Network Name')
>
> param  virtualNetworkName  string = 'azure_postgresql_vnet'
>
>   
>
> @description('Subnet Name')
>
> param  subnetName  string = 'azure_postgresql_subnet'
>
>   
>
> @description('Virtual Network RuleName')
>
> param  virtualNetworkRuleName  string = 'AllowSubnet'
>
>   
>
> @description('Virtual Network Address Prefix')
>
> param  vnetAddressPrefix  string = '10.0.0.0/16'
>
>   
>
> @description('Subnet Address Prefix')
>
> param  subnetPrefix  string = '10.0.0.0/16'
>
>   
>
> var  firewallrules = [
>
> {
>
> Name: 'rule1'
>
> StartIpAddress: '0.0.0.0'
>
> EndIpAddress: '255.255.255.255'
>
> }
>
> {
>
> Name: 'rule2'
>
> StartIpAddress: '0.0.0.0'
>
> EndIpAddress: '255.255.255.255'
>
> }
>
> ]
>
>   
>
> resource  vnet  'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2021-05-01' = {
>
> name: virtualNetworkName
>
> location: location
>
> properties: {
>
> addressSpace: {
>
> addressPrefixes: [
>
> vnetAddressPrefix
>
> ]
>
> }
>
> }
>
> }
>
>   
>
> resource  subnet 
> 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2021-05-01' = {
>
> parent: vnet
>
> name: subnetName
>
> properties: {
>
> addressPrefix: subnetPrefix
>
> }
>
> }
>
>   
>
> resource  server  'Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers@2017-12-01' = {
>
> name: serverName
>
> location: location
>
> sku: {
>
> name: skuName
>
> tier: skuTier
>
> capacity: skuCapacity
>
> size: '${skuSizeMB}'
>
> family: skuFamily
>
> }
>
> properties: {
>
> createMode: 'Default'
>
> version: postgresqlVersion
>
> administratorLogin: administratorLogin
>
> administratorLoginPassword: administratorLoginPassword
>
> storageProfile: {
>
> storageMB: skuSizeMB
>
> backupRetentionDays: backupRetentionDays
>
> geoRedundantBackup: environment  ==  'production'  ?  'Enabled'  : 
> 'Disabled'
>
> }
>
> }
>
>   
>
> resource  virtualNetworkRule  'virtualNetworkRules@2017-12-01' = {
>
> name: virtualNetworkRuleName
>
> properties: {
>
> virtualNetworkSubnetId: subnet.id
>
> ignoreMissingVnetServiceEndpoint: true
>
> }
>
> }
>
> }
>
>   
>
> @batchSize(1)
>
> resource  firewallRules 
> 'Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers/firewallRules@2017-12-01' = [for 
> rule  in  firewallrules: {
>
> parent: server
>
> name: '${rule.Name}'
>
> properties: {
>
> startIpAddress: rule.StartIpAddress
>
> endIpAddress: rule.EndIpAddress
>
> }
>
> }]
> ```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

**Portal:-**

[image]

Coming to your error code you can find the Feature that is not registered for PostgreSQL resource by running the below commands from this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/feature?view=azure-cli-latest#az-feature-list) in your Azure CLI:-

> ```bash
> az feature list --namespace Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL
> ```

Output:-

[image]

Find feature that is not registered according to the region in which you're trying to Deploy your PostgreSQL and then run command below from this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/feature?view=azure-cli-latest#az-feature-register) to register the feature:-

> ```bash
> az feature register --name <name-of-the-feature> --namespace
> Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL
> ```

Additionally, Refer this [Github issue1](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/8534) and [Github issue2](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/7265) for the error that you're facing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the extensive description. I made the conditions work now. *yay* So that works perfectly now. However, I saw the errors resulted from an another issue. I have to follow azure policies that were blocking my deployment, but didn't return a proper error description :(